# Uncaught ReferenceError: ChromeSamples is not defined at (index):24:1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nfc

When testing out [Web NFC](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/) and following the script example given by GoogleChrome on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/web-nfc) I get error when trying to deploy my site on [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com). How can I fix it?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ChromeSamples is not defined
at (index):24:1
```

The error is reffering to index.html (see full script on Github link) files following lines:

```
<script>
log = ChromeSamples.log;

if (!("NDEFReader" in window))
  ChromeSamples.setStatus("Web NFC is not available. Use Chrome on Android.");
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the [output_helper.html](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/_includes/output_helper.html). The repo you linked is using Jekyll as a templating engine so you need to check for any `{% include ... %}` statements

Comment: Well... I don't see ChromeSamples defined anywhere

Comment: @Falling10fruit, sorry, but I don't understand how should I define ChromeSamples. Google doesn't help me to understand that..

Comment: @Phil How can I include output_helper.html? Where and how should I check for the {% include ... %} statements?

Comment: Notice how the [index.html](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/web-nfc/index.html) has `{% include output_helper.html`? That's a template include directive. If you're not using Jekyll yourself, you'll need to just copy the markup and code from [output_helper.html](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/_includes/output_helper.html) and place it in the appropriate position in your HTML

Comment: What is `ChromeSamples` supposed to be? A variable? A function? A class? An object?

Comment: @Falling10fruit I think ChromeSamples is a class?

Comment: @Phil I am super overwhelmed right now.. As I found out Jekyll is a template that uses Ruby? I don't use Ruby in my project. So I just have to paste in the line {% include output_helper.html} the code from output_helper.html? I can do that but what to do with '{% if page.check_min_version %}' line in it?  Because browser just outputs '{% if page.check_min_version %}' in that line.

Comment: And why is the index.HTML file so wierd in GoogleChrome script example? I mean the HTML file doesn't start with the reguler lines like <!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, <body>. Is that because the author of this repository is using Jekyll templating engine?

Comment: 1) _"So I just have to paste in the line"_... correct. 2) _"what to do with `{% if page.check_min_version %}`"_... just leave that whole block out (lines 36 - 46 inclusive), it's only adding some JS that checks the browser version. 3) _"And why is the index.HTML file so wierd"_... it's just another piece of content that is included into an overall layout. 4) _"Is that because the author of this repository is using Jekyll"_... yes

Comment: FYI, you can see the rendered final rendered result / complete HTML here ~ https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/ (right click and view source)

Comment: Then to define a class, you type `class ChromeSamples { constructor () {}; };`

Comment: Thank you Falling10fruit for your comment! File "output_helper.html" already had ChromeSamples defined so including it in my "index.html" file as @Phil described it also helped. Created my own answer with link to a working repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Have to include the [output_helper.html](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/_includes/output_helper.html) content into the following index.html line:

```
{% include output_helper.html initial_output_content=initial_output_content %}
```

**Why?** Because the repository in the link is using Jekyll (it's a templating engine for Ruby) and automatically fills this index.html line with output_helper.html contents. If you are not using Jekyll then you have to manually insert the linked contents.

[Here](https://github.com/Ted-Rose/read_write_nfc_javascript) is a repository with NFC reader and writer working in Google chrome. Star the repository if it helped you!

Thank you @Phil for providing this answer in the comments!